# How do I upgrade the OS on my Galaxy S2 I9100MUGKG2

Tags: samsung

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.  I don't know what's wrong with me.  Maybe I"m losing it.  I'm a Software Engineer with an honors degree in Computer Science and I CAN'T FIGURE IT OUT!

I am absolutely at my wits end.  lol  Help me before I do the unspeakable.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an update available for your android phone in android you go to 
Settings -> About Phone -> System Updates

Good Luck!